# How to combine/merge/intersect two arrays of objects in one loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

This code works, but I feel there must be a better way without having to use `Array.find()` twice.

```js
const people = [
  { id: 0, age: 99 },
  { id: 1, age: 54 },
  { id: 2, age: 54 }
];
const roles = [
  { pId: 0, responsabilites: ['make money'] },
  { pId: 1, responsabilites: ['make money', 'complain'] },
  { pId: 4, responsabilites: ['make the world a better place', 'sarcasmm'] },
];

let roomsAndOrders = people.filter(p => {
  return roles.find(r => r.pId === p.id);
});
roomsAndOrders = roomsAndOrders.map(p => {
  let r = roles.find(r => r.pId === p.id);
  return { ...r, ...p };
});
   
console.log(roomsAndOrders);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one `.map`. Your original `filter` doesn't make much sense - `filter` filters out elements from an array that you don't want, but it doesn't change the elements. You're returning objects from your `filter` function, and objects are truthy, so the `filter` doesn't actually do anything.

Edit: Or just map the other way around - map from `roles` to `people` all at once, rather than mapping from `people` to `roles`.

```js
const people = [
  { id: 0, age: 99 },
  { id: 1, age: 54 },
  { id: 2, age: 54 }
];
const roles = [
  { pId: 0, responsabilites: ['make money'] },
  { pId: 1, responsabilites: ['make money', 'complain'] },
];

const roomsAndOrders = roles.map(role => {
  const person = people.find(({ id }) => role.pId === id);
  return { ...role, ...person };
});
console.log(roomsAndOrders);
```

To only include objects whose IDs are in both arrays, you will have to use `.reduce` instead, since `map` always returns the same number of elements as in the original array:

```js
const people = [
  { id: 0, age: 99 },
  { id: 1, age: 54 },
  { id: 2, age: 54 }
];
const roles = [
  { pId: 0, responsabilites: ['make money'] },
  { pId: 1, responsabilites: ['make money', 'complain'] },
  { pId: 4, responsabilites: ['make the world a better place', 'sarcasmm'] },
];

const roomsAndOrders = roles.reduce((accum, role) => {
  const person = people.find(({ id }) => role.pId === id);
  if (person) accum.push({ ...role, ...person });
  return accum;
}, []);
console.log(roomsAndOrders);
```

Comment: if you notice the last result object (age 54) doesn't have the `pId` key. That's the reason I used `filter`. Otherwise, I get objects that don't have a matching `id`. *actually* mine was also broken. I fixed the `filter` function

Comment: Spread operator is not supported by all browsers. If you use in your code, please tick **Use BabelJS / ES2015** checkbox.

Comment: @GianfrancoP. If your original result wasn't what you were actually trying for, see my edit: just map the other way around instead, and that way you don't have to `filter`.

Comment: @GianfrancoP. `.find` will return `null|object`. When you do `{ ...a, ...b}`, null values are handled and hence can be ignore. But to be safe, you can always use `.find(...) || {}`

Comment: one last thing. What if I want to discard any object if they don't a matching `x.id == y.pid` in either array?
see the new role with `pId: 4`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in O(n) using a hashtable:

```
 const result = [], hash = {};

 for(const person of people)
   result.push(hash[person.id] = {...person});

for(const role of roles)
  if(hash[role.pId])
    Object.assign(hash[role.pId], role);
```